# grid focus issue in ExtJS4

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs3

We are using ExtJS4 in our application. We have a problem with grid focus.We are using `grid.getView().focusEl.focus()` in ExtJS3. Now it seems that this is not working.What is the replacement for this one in ExtJS4.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have helped you checked on the differences in ExtJS3 and ExtJS4, the major changes is the focusEl has been removed from the gridView element.

**In ExtJS3, focusEl is the anchor link in the view**

```
<div class="x-grid3-scroller" id="ext-gen10" style="width: 298px; height: 174px; ">
    <div class="x-grid3-body" style="width:100px;" id="ext-gen12">
        <div class="x-grid3-row x-grid3-row-first x-grid3-row-last" style="width:100px;">
            <table class="x-grid3-row-table" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:100px;">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><td class="x-grid3-col x-grid3-cell x-grid3-td-0 x-grid3-cell-first " style="width: 100px;" tabindex="0"><div class="x-grid3-cell-inner x-grid3-col-0" unselectable="on">0</div></td></tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" class="x-grid3-focus" tabindex="-1" id="ext-gen13"></a>
</div>
```

**In ExtJS4, this anchor link doesn't exist**

**Solution**

This is a small [fiddle test](http://jsfiddle.net/chaoszcat/BAFF2/1/) I have created for you. Basically what you need to change is as follow:

```
grid.getView().el.focus();
```

Instead of getting the focusEl (an anchor link), we use the whole element.

Hope this solve your problem.

Comment: grid.getView().focus() also works and may be a cleaner approach.